# Clearfix does not work on all pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, clearfix

On my site http://jonasolaussen.se/?page_id=16 as you see the text goes under the footer, I does get better if I ad `<div style="cleare:none;"> </div>` as it does on the other sites.

Does someone have an solution, i would be grateful!

Comment: Doesn't look like a clearing problem.  It is your absolutely positioned footer staying on top of everything.

Comment: My footer has the positioning absolute becasue i want it to always be att the bottom of the page, despite the content. 

But when i ad "div style="clear:both;" " it works on the other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues:

**1)** There is an extra `</div><!--wrapper-->` that needs to be removed.
**2)** The `div` `.footer_fix_pusher` needs to be cleared (I have used your clear fix method below)

```
<div style="clear:both"></div> <!--You need to add this-->
</div><!--footer_fix_pusher-->
</div><!--wrapper--> <!--You need to delete this closing tag-->
```

Comment: Thank you!

You are a wounderful person!